# What is the right punctuation for a series of questions within a single sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, lists

What is the right punctuation to use with a list of examples that are questions? For example:

> This is a list of statements from the texts that I find vague: "From what are the interiors of a heart built?", "And that of a prison?", "does the bird sing when it dies?", "does the bird bring good or bad luck?", and "How could something so small carry a heavy load?".

Answer (score 2):

That is punctuated very well. You introduced the list with a colon, preserved the puctuation of each sentence within quote marks, preserved (I presume) their capitalization, and separated each with commas.

Well done!

The only thing I might suggest is that you include *ellipsis* in front of the ones that don't start with a capital (if they are, as they seem to be, *sentence fragments*.)

For example:
". . . does the bird bring bad or good luck?"

(However, if these were actually complete sentences in the text you quote from, they should be capitalized when you cite them.)